# How can I find Percentage using difference between 2 DateTime counts?

Tags: looker-studio

I am looking for a way to take the number of [Closed Time] records as a total count and subtract from the number of [Open Time] records as a total count to be able to find the percentage of closed tickets.

To explain a little more, every ticket has a [Open Time] that is in a DateTime format. When a ticket is closed, a [Closed Time] is entered in the data source in a DateTime format. So I am looking to find out the percentage of tickets that were opened that are now closed.

Tried to use

```
SUM(COUNT_DISTINCT(OPEN TIME) - COUNT_DISTINCT(CLOSED TIME))
```

to create the difference but get an error that "Re-aggregating metrics is not supported." and using something like Date_Diff only give me the time between the 2 dimensions on a per ticket basis but not a total count of records so that i can convert into a percentage.

Data Studio Dimensions:
[image: Data Studio Dimensions]

Comment: [As of REVISION 1] **Needs details**: Could you provide a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (TO-DO) (and sample data set(s) / Google Sheet (TO-DO)) of the scenario, that shows 1) Input table(s) (~10 rows) (in both Report (TO-DO) & Question (TO-DO)) 2) Expected output (in both Report (TO-DO) & Question (TO-DO)) 3) An attempt at solving the issue (in both Report (TO-DO) & Question (DONE))? Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to visualise and pinpoint a suggestion to a specific use case

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by using the following calculated field setup for the data source:

```
 COUNT_DISTINCT(Closed time)/COUNT_DISTINCT(Open Time).
```

This can then be changed from a number to a percent using the edit ability of Data Studio.

Comment: [As of REVISION 2] **Needs details** (as the question and now answer lack inputs): Could you provide a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (TO-DO) (and sample data set(s) / Google Sheet (TO-DO)) of the scenario, that shows 1) Input table(s) (~9 rows) (in both Report (TO-DO) & Question (TO-DO)) 2) Actual output (in both Report (TO-DO) & Question (TO-DO))? Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to visualise the suggestion and thus adapt it to similar use cases.